# PHP API Security

Tags: php, api, security

The problem I have is I don't know what I need to do to make my PHP API secure. I've considered using encryption or authentication, but I don't know enough about either. My question is, what is both an easy and strong measure to take when making a secure API?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Other that "I want to use encryption" it is hard to tell what you're actually asking. Do try and focus your question.

Comment: Reworded and should be more clear what I am looking for in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your web server configuration it wouldn't be a big afford to set up a TLS/SSL encryption with self generated (OpenSSL, it's free) keys. Because the technique uses asynchronous encryption there is no cipher that's being sent. Also you can check the authentication by signing all valid certificates by the same (also self generated) certificate authority and allow only these clients access to your API.